# How to use options and settings in azuredeploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-deployment, .net-core-3.1

Following the documentation [Working with options and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings) with DI in `Azure Function v3` and `dotnet core 3.1` work perfectly.

But I am in search for set parameters in format option:setting i have in my local.settgins.json in azuredeploy.json

When testing to deploy with an ARM project in Visual Studio, I have this error.
I didn't try yet, but I need to set a parameter for different environments in `Azure DevOps` pipeline variable too.

Thanks a lot for all the help.

**The error**

> ```
> failed with message '{
>   "Code": "BadRequest",
>   "Message": "AppSetting with name 'option:setting' is not allowed.",
>   "Target": null,
>   "Details": [
>     {
>       "Message": "AppSetting with name 'option:setting' is not allowed."
>     },
>     {
>       "Code": "BadRequest"
>     },
>     {
>       "ErrorEntity": {
>         "ExtendedCode": "04072",
>         "MessageTemplate": "AppSetting with name '{0}' is not allowed.",
>         "Parameters": [
>           "option:setting"
>         ],
>         "Code": "BadRequest",
>         "Message": "AppSetting with name 'option:setting' is not allowed."
>       }
>     }
>   ],
>   "Innererror": null
> }'
> ```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "option:setting": "value"
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddOptions<MyOption>()
                .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) => configuration.GetSection("option").Bind(settings));
        }
    }
}
```

**azuredeploy.parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    ...
    "option": {
      "value": {
        "setting": "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**azuredeploy.json**

```
"resources": [
{
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "name": "functionApp",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "properties": {
    "parameters": {
      ...
      "additionalAppSettings": {
        "value": {
          "MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES": "1",
          "option:setting": "[parameters('option').setting]"
        }
      }
    },
    "debugSetting": {
      "detailLevel": "requestContent,responseContent"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"...testing the deploy with Visual Studio"?_
Are you speaking about the **Publish** from within Visual Studio with the **Web Deploy** mechanism?

Comment: Before publish, i deploy from a ARM project on Visual Studio. This is here the error appear.

Comment: configuration.GetSection("option") in startup.cs should be Values(see local.settings.json) in my opinion.

Comment: Appreciate you share your solution here which can benefit others who has same puzzle with you. You can [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others can directly know it is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in the documentation [Configure an App Service app in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/app-service/configure-common#add-or-edit)

Simply edit your local.settings.json and replace char : with __ (**there is 2 char**).

The **GetSection** method work fine with it.

And now do the same with the azuredeploy.json.

Voila, the deploy work perfectly and Cerise sur le gateau, it work on Linux too.

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "option__setting": "value"
  }
}
```

**azuredeploy.json**

```
"resources": [
{
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "name": "functionApp",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "properties": {
    "parameters": {
      ...
      "additionalAppSettings": {
        "value": {
          "MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES": "1",
          "option__setting": "[parameters('option').setting]"
        }
      }
    },
    "debugSetting": {
      "detailLevel": "requestContent,responseContent"
    }
  }
},
```